# How to perform level expansion on bar chart visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have  a bar chart visual. I can right click on bar and choose drill down which gives me bar chart for data inside the bar.

How can I perform level down expansion on bar chart (like matrix expansion). Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drill down option that is present in your visual, you can get your expected result by clicking on "Expand All Down One Level In The Hierarchy" Option.

p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in". :)